# Replace quotes in an array

Tags: array, merge, string, number

I'm trying to use a charting library within a Craft template.

The chart expects an array of numbers that I'm building up from a table but I'm getting an array of strings instead.

```
{% set donutData = [] %}
{% for p in block.donutValues %}
    {% set donutData = donutData|merge([
        p.value
    ]) %}
{% endfor %}
```

and then if I do `{{ donutData|json_encode }}` I get an array of strings returned that my chart library can't interpret.

`value` is set to be a number field in the Craft table column so not sure why I'm getting a string returned.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that even although the Craft field is set to `number` it doesn't actually define a number.

I changed the field from a regular Craft table field to a Super Table field and my `{{ donutData|json_encode }}` corrects spits out an array of numbers.